# SQL How to show '0' value for a month, if no data exists in the table for that month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

First of all my result looks like this:

| KONTONR | Month | SELSKAPSKODE | BELOP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 459611 | 1 | BAGA | 156000 |
| 459611 | 2 | BAGA | 73000 |
| 459611 | 4 | BAGA | 217000 |
| 459611 | 5 | BAGA | 136000 |
| 459611 | 1 | CIVO | 45896 |
| 459611 | 3 | CIVO | 32498 |
| 459611 | 4 | CIVO | 9841 |
| 330096 | 1 | BAGA | 42347 |
| 330096 | 3 | BAGA | 3695 |

I'm trying to show month 2 month bookings on several accounts, per account (`KONTONR`) there are several codes (`SELSKAPSKODE`) on which bookings are recorded (the sum of the bookings as `BELOP`). I would like to give an overview of the sum of the bookings (`BELOP`) per account (`KONTONR`) per month per code (`SELSKAPSKODE`). My problem is the codes don't show in a month if no bookings are made on that code. Is there a way to fix this? I understand why the codes don't show, since they're simply not in the table I'm querying. And I suspect that the solution is in making a 'fake' table which I then join (left outer join?) with 'another' table.
I just can't get it to work, I'm pretty new to SQL. Can someone please help?
My query looks like this (I only inserted the 'nested' query to make a set-up for a join, if this makes sense?!):

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT KONTONR, Month, SELSKAPSKODE, BELOP
FROM (
    SELECT SELSKAPSKODE, KONTONR, SKIPS_KODE, MONTH(POSTDATO) AS Month, SUM(BELOP) AS BELOP
    FROM dbo.T99_DETALJ
    WHERE (POSTDATO >= '2012-01-01') AND (BILAGSART = 0 OR BILAGSART = 2)
    GROUP BY SELSKAPSKODE, KONTONR, SKIPS_KODE, MONTH(POSTDATO)
    ) AS T99_summary
GROUP BY KONTONR, SELSKAPSKODE, Month, BELOP
ORDER BY KONTONR, SELSKAPSKODE, Month
```

So concluding I would like to 'fill up' the missing months (see table at the start), for instance for account (`KONTONR`) 459611 month 3 is 'missing'. I would like to show month 3, with the sum of the bookings (`BELOP`) as '0'. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Data Base Server are you using ?

Comment: The application is running on Microsoft SQL Server 2005, but i'm using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio to 'get to' the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query a table with the values 1-12 and left outer join your result.

Here is a sample using a table variable instead of your query and a CTE to build a table with numbers.

```
declare @T table
(
  Month int
)

insert into @T values(1)
insert into @T values(1)
insert into @T values(1)
insert into @T values(3)
insert into @T values(3)

;with Months(Month) as
(
  select 1
  union all
  select Month + 1
  from Months
  where Month < 12
)
select M.Month,
       count(T.Month) Count,
       isnull(sum(T.Month), 0) Sum
from Months as M
  left outer join @T as T
    on M.Month = T.Month
group by M.Month
```

Result:

```
Month       Count       Sum
----------- ----------- -----------
1           3           3
2           0           0
3           2           6
4           0           0
5           0           0
6           0           0
7           0           0
8           0           0
9           0           0
10          0           0
11          0           0
12          0           0
```

Comment: Thank you for your sollution. Can 'insert' my query instead of your table creation? I don't get it to work entirely

Comment: @Benne - `@T` is instead of your query. So you should replace `left outer join @T as T` with `left outer join (your query goes here) as T`

Comment: To give a little more info. I put my query instead of your parameter @T. And i removed the 'nested' part. And then I make the join to 'my' dbo.T99_DETALJ table. But it just shows the table I already got from my query. Obviously I'm doing something wrong :-) but I can't figure it out. Could you maybe point me (even) more in the direction? Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you I got the 'code' to work, however I'm not sure it does what I need. I want to show the the list of SELSKAPSKODE behind the month, even when no booking (BELOP) are made on the SELSKAPSKODE (which are actually shipnames). Do I just need to rearrange Groupby, orderby al little? or do I need different code, or maybe join the tables not on months?

Comment: So I guess what I need is to make the cte with an extra column with  all the SELSKAPSKODE, right? And then make the join. Is it possible to 'populate' the column in the cte, based on the SELSKAPSKODE in the 'original' table? So I don't need to manually update the column in the cte everytime a SELKSKODE (Ship) is added to the fleet?

Comment: @Benne - I don't think I can provide any more help with your actual query. I don't have your table structures and I actually don't understand it with the sub-queries, double group by and `top 100 percent`.

Comment: I think it is time for me to rethink my approach. Thank you very much for your help this far!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to do all that you could also modify this: SUM(BELOP) with this:
Sum (case when BELOP is not null then 1 else 0 end)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add in the year if you have a creation date for the interactions you are counting which may be helpful if your interactions span the course of many years.

```
with Months(Month) as
(
  select 1
  union all
  select Month + 1
  from Months
  where Month < 12
)
select M.Month, year(CreatedOn) as Year,
       count(amount) Count,
       isnull(sum(amount), 0) Sum
from Months as M
  left outer join Charge as C
    on M.Month = (month(CreatedOn))
group by M.Month, year(CreatedOn) order by year(CreatedOn)
```

[image: output]